# Display content of shared memory section in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

I've got a couple of programs that communicate using a named memory section. Is there any way that I can view the contents of this shared memory section from WinDBG, either in user mode or kernel mode? I don't have a pointer to it, but I do know the name.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find out? Getting the address of the named section is quite easy using Process Explorer from Sysinternals and using LiveKD I can inspect that FILE_OBJECT but I'm stuck on how getting to the *contents* itself. Following [this](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=280) takes me to the CONTROL_AREA containing an _EX_FAST_REF as FilePointer.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to do this on our shared memory without getting exactly what you want, but I'm putting notes here for posterity:

- I couldn't find an easy way to get a handle from a name, but if you do "!handle 0 f" and then search through the output you can see the names of your kernel objects and their handle ids: get handle from this.
- obviously the shared memory kernel object doesn't have the process-specific address in it, but
  .call /s KnownFuncWithSamePrototype MapViewOfFileEx does return what looks like a valid pointer

You need full symbols for '.call' to work but you don't have that for MapViewOfFile(Ex), I happened to find a function that returned a pointer and took six params in our code, so I didn't have to recompile to get this to work (that's what KnownFuncWithSamePrototype means above). I'm not sure if this is an option for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using a user-mode debugger... would it be possible for you to write a very simple test app that acquires access to the named memory section (i.e. calls OpenFileMapping then MapViewOfFile), and then run that app under a debugger?  You should be able to step past the calls to get access to the section, and then inspect that app's view of the section.

(In case it helps, the "Second Process" heading on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx) provides sample code for a process to access a named, shared memory section and map it into its address space.)

I'm generally a fan of writing small test tools to help out debugging things like this...  If you want to make things easier, you can even write the test tool to automatically break into any attached debuggers (using a function like DebugBreak).